# How to pass a variable into a dialog function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do i pass my rating variable  from updateRating() function into my window.location.replace(url + rating) which in the "proceed" function in my dialog?

Here are my codes:

```
         <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".hireraccept").click(function(){
                     $('.jRating').jRating();
                     $("#dialog-rate").dialog("open");
                     itervalue = $(this).attr("value");


                    return false

        });


        $("#dialog-rate").dialog({

            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: false,
            height: 200,
            width: 200,        
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Proceed": function(){

                    window.location.replace("{{ domain_url }}/workroom/accept/" + itervalue +"/" + rating);
                    $(this).dialog("close");

                }

            }


        }); }); </script>






  <script> 
  function updateRating(rate,proceed){
  goodtogo = proceed;

  rating = rate;

}  
</script>
```

Comment: Where is this mystical updateRating() function?

Comment: @Hamish how do i accept when they are not answers in my opinion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that your variables `goodtogo` and `rating` are variables that are local to the function `updateRating()`. All you have to do is declare them within the global scope.

```
var goodtogo, rating;
function updateRating(value) {
    goodtogo = true;
    rating = value;
}
```

Comment: Does it matter if they dont belong to the same script tag?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to create a global variable. Assign the value to it where it is appropriate. Then access it from within the "dialog"

Comment: Does it help if they are not from the same script tags? one is under document.ready tag, the other function is not..